# Hacked WordPress website, as notified by Google Search Console, what to do?

Tags: hacked

I just received a second email from Google Search Console, that one of my websites, [Emma&Nala Jewelry](http://emmaandnala.com) was hacked. In the email, they have sent two URL's that they found to be "suspicious":

1. http://emmaandnala.com/jlyesvgliktwgsg-b899-n26339-gslk/
2. http://emmaandnala.com/n34104-kfkou-b890-xxptoayz/

**The website config stats:**

- Linux Hosting at [Avalon hosting, Business package](https://www.avalon.hr/web-hosting/)
- Wordpress 4.8, updated before this posting
- Plugins:

  - Akismet v3.3.3
  - Contact Form 7 v4.8.1
  - Envato WordPress Toolkit v1.7.3
  - Google Analytics by Yoast v6.2.0
  - Hello Dolly v1.6
  - Instagram feed v1.4.9
  - Instagrate to WordPress v1.2.7
  - Mailchimp for WordPress Lite v4.1.5
  - NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati v2.2.10
  - Post Duplicator v2.20
  - Regenerate thumbnails v2.2.6
  - RevolutionSLider v4.1.4
  - Simply Instagram v1.3.3
  - WooCommerce v3.1.1

    - Woocommerce Category Best Seller Widget v1.0
    - WooCommerce Google Analytics Integration v1.4.3
    - WooCommerce Header Category Image v1.0.0
  - WooDojo v1.5.4
  - WordPress Importer v0.6.3
  - WordpressSEO by Yoast v5.1
  - WP Retina2x v5.0.5
  - WPBakery Visual Composer v4.3.4

**Events timeline:**

1. **12th July 2017** I receive email from Google Search Console team that someone else was added as admin of Search Console property for that website
2. I log into search console, remove these individuals (silly gmail account)
3. I removed the verification .html file from the site root dir. as well, and re-verified myself as an admin (re-added the property)
4. this morning, **27th July 2017** I receive email from Google again, listing the two above URL's as malicious

**What I did:**

- checked web server **file-system** for any suspicious files/folders -> nothing there
- **updated** WordPress to 4.8
- **updated** plugins
- **removed all WP users** except myself (admin)

Before I start messing up with `wp.config` and similar, is there anything else I can do? Skills level: self-taught newbie in unix, .js, python and a bit of sql flavors out there.

Many thanks for help!

EDIT 1: 
Here are the results of the WordFence scan if anybody would like to take a closer look :)

[Wordfence scan results in a GoogleDocs file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PrAITrHzlpj7hQjOWfPhviGQva8f9sICBBAGVG4NjCs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds like you have an actively exploited hole somewhere. _Do not_ rely on random internet advice for this, you need someone with security expertise scrubbing the site. At the very least try to get your hosting security team involved. Without knowing what the issue is and closing it your only option is probably a full rebuild and getting rid of any less than very established plugin.

Comment: I bet your website was hacked through Revolution Slider. That plugin has more security gaps than I have hair on my head.

Answer (score 1):

1st - Scan and identified malwares using this free tool https://sitecheck.sucuri.net if gives you files infected just delete them from your build.

2nd - Install sucuri plugin on your website and run again.

3rd - Change passwords on the admin users

4rd - Check for exploits on plugins on this site - https://www.exploit-db.com/

5th - Install Wordfence Security plugin

6th - Update urgently RevolutionSLider to the latest version

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Here's a screenshot of what Sucuri plug-in says (I can't make any sense of this) [Here a Screenshot](https://ibb.co/dRCHVQ)

Comment: @AlexStarbuck install the plugin Sucuri and run the scan through the plugin and let me know how it goes

Comment: I did that ;), check out my comment above yours, it says "Here is a Screenshot". Click on this and you will see a screenshot of my WP admin > Sucuri and the results. It found some core WP files as modified but it doesnt let me do anything with these. What should I do?

Comment: @AlexStarbuck you should replace those files, and than apply file & folder permission through your cPanel

Comment: Nuno, here are the results of the WordFence plugin scan. [WordFence virus scan results](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PrAITrHzlpj7hQjOWfPhviGQva8f9sICBBAGVG4NjCs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AlexStarbuck - I can't see your latest screenshot